# SQL Server: SQL taking very long time to execute

Tags: sql-server

I have an sql query which is taking very long time to execute and below are the details of the sql.

```
select *
from 
(
select SiteID, tDate, tTime, (CASE WHEN IsNumeric(tMI)=1 then cast(tMI as float) ELSE null END) AS value
from Raw_Data
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for SiteID in ([CA0021], [CA0022], [CA0059])
) piv
where 
(tDate>='20151201' and tDate<='20151205') 
order by tDate
```

What can I do to optimize this query i.e. increase its performance?

the sql result as below :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AuVO.jpg)

Comment: how big is the table? which index have the table?

Comment: can you share indexes and actual execution plan.

Comment: the database size more than 5GB

Comment: from my sql query it take almost 3 minute to show the execution result

Comment: Try the first approach I have mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from your query that the base table i.e. `Raw_Data` contains a lot of records. If that is true, then you could try the steps mentioned below to optimize your scenario.

1. you need to make sure that an index on`tDate` column is there for the table `Raw_Data` and furthermore this index has included columns of `SiteID, tTime, tMI` (sample query for this is mentioned at end of this answer)
2. create an index on `SiteID` column
3. Move the filter on `tDate` to inside the main query

**Query with filters inside the main query**

```
    select *
    from 
    (   select SiteID, tDate, tTime,
          (CASE WHEN IsNumeric(tMI)=1 then cast(tMI   as float) 
              ELSE null END) AS value
          from Raw_Data 
          where 
         (tDate>='20151201' and tDate<='20151205') 
      ) src
     pivot
     (
       max(value) for SiteID in ([CA0021], [CA0022], [CA0059])
      ) piv    
    order by tDate
```

**Creating index with included columns**

```
create NONCLUSTERED index index1 on Raw_Data
(
  tDate ASC
)
include ( SiteID, tTime, tMI )
```

**ANOTHER APPROACH**

Also, another approach you could take is to run your query in `SQL Server Management Studio` with the query option checked for `Include Actual Execution Plan`.

If the execution plan has a recommendation for creating an index ( this normally shows in green font), then you should create the recommended index and see if that helps your query speed. I have observed from my experience that execution plan recommendations always work and result in a great improvement.

Comment: Big thanks to you, it really works

Answer (score 0):

Adding the filter for tDate and SiteId to the select query that produces the data (... from rawData where tDate between x and y and SiteId In (a, b, c)... will improve it

Comment: can you explain this via exact sql query?